# Sqoop export job failed after map 100%

Tags: hadoop, hive, export, sqoop

I'm trying to export a table from HDFS to Oracle database, using the command:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port/db --username user -P --table OPORTUNIDADESHIVE --export-dir /user/hadoop/OPORTUNIDADES/000000_0 --input-fields-terminated-by "\t"
```

where OPORTUNIDADESHIVE is the table from Oracle and the file "000000_0" is the table extracted from Hive to HDFS. Both tables have the same columns.

This table from Hive is ROW FORMAT DELIMITED and FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'.

But in the end, the export gives me this error message:

> 2021-11-04 14:58:04,633 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
> 2021-11-04 14:58:13,711 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
> 2021-11-04 14:58:13,723 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1635324128846_0049
> failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed
> task_1635324128846_0049_m_000000 Job failed as tasks failed.
> failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0 killedMaps:0 killedReduces: 0
>
> 2021-11-04 14:58:13,792 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 9
> Job Counters
> Failed map tasks=2
> Killed map tasks=2
> Launched map tasks=2
> Data-local map tasks=2
> Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=28818
> Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
> Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=14409
> Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=14409
> Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=29509632 2021-11-04 14:58:13,799 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group
> FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead 2021-11-04
> 14:58:13,800 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in
> 19.1507 seconds (0 bytes/sec) 2021-11-04 14:58:13,803 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is
> deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
> 2021-11-04 14:58:13,804 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0
> records. 2021-11-04 14:58:13,804 ERROR mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Export
> job failed! 2021-11-04 14:58:13,804 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error
> during export: Export job failed!
> at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:445)
> at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.exportTable(OracleManager.java:465)
> at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:80)
> at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
> at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
> at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
> at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
> at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
> at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)

Comment: Did you check the map attempt logs?

Comment: where are those logs placed?

Answer (score 0):

sqoop export is very sensitive to data type, length mismatch issue. so plese follow below steps to fix this issue -

1. Put hive and oracle definition side by side and check if data type and length are comparable. please note some data type like string in hive can hold more than 4000 char so you may need to handle such scenario specially.
2. if you see above comparison is fine then use this command to import data. Your command has `export dir` argument, it should be path to the table which is `/user/hadoop/OPORTUNIDADES`.
   But i feel like its easy to use `--hcatalog-table` and here is complete command.

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydb:5217/user --username user --password pass --hcatalog-database hive_db --hcatalog-table hive_tab --table orac_tab --input-null-string '\\\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\\\N' --m 6
```

Pls note we are using just input and output table and optional null handling.

Comment: i've used this create command for both oracle and hive table:
create table xpto(
ID INT,
Anuncio VARCHAR(200),
LotesAnuncio VARCHAR(200),
TipoContrato VARCHAR(100),
ValorPreco VARCHAR(200),
IsRenovavel INT,
CritRelCusto VARCHAR(200),
IsPrestCaucao INT,
RefInterna VARCHAR(2000),
Portal VARCHAR(30),
LinkOportunidade VARCHAR(2000),
TipoOportunidade INT,
DtEnvPubDre VARCHAR(25),
DataAdicionado VARCHAR(25),
DtProp VARCHAR(25),
DtEsc VARCHAR(25),
DtSub VARCHAR(25),
DtValProp VARCHAR(25),
First INT,
DesigEnt VARCHAR(4000),
DesigContrato VARCHAR(4000),
SucContrato VARCHAR(4000))

Comment: when i try to use --hcatalog-table it give me an exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory /tmp/hadoop/8fba1d1b-28bd-4fce-aa1a-025062f4396c on fs file:///

Comment: could you pls share complete sqoop export command that you are using?

Comment: pls note, you can use either hcatalog-table or export dir and not both

Comment: i've figured out what the problem was. the fields from the table were terminated with '\t' and to do the export it only works when the fields are terminated with ','
thank you anyway for your help.